# Why do 40mm Grenade launchers have short barrels?

Tags: firearms

Wouldnt they have more muzzle velocity and range if the barrels were longer? Is it because of increased recoil? If yes, could a longer barrel be used without increasing the recoil and if so how?

Comment: Long barrels and rifling perhaps? Are they designed for short range? For long range they use bombs and missiles... Also, recoil will be based on Newton's third law...

Comment: They would be more accurate too. So would many other weapons yet they do not do that. But do you really need extra range, accuracy, or muzzle velocity in a grenade launcher? It's a grenade so needs neither accuracy nor high velocity upon impact, and that also means it's effective range is longer for the same muzzle velocity compared to a bullet.  Plus it is an auxiliary weapon so you reallly do not want it to be heavier and more unwieldly.  But a longer barrel probably decreases recoil due to the extra weight.

Comment: Note, however, even stationary launchers also have short barrels so it's probably that a low pressure propellant does not get much benefit from a longer barrel.